# Does g++ compiler have graphical user interface?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, g++

As the question says, I wonder if the default ubuntu compiler, g++, has graphical user interface.

Comment: Are you looking for an application in which you can select source file(s) and compiler options?

Comment: yes, now I was just referring particularly to g++

Answer (score 5, accepted):

g++ is strictly only the compiler and so operates solely from the terminal. However, there are many good graphical IDEs that make use of the g++ compiler such as Code::Blocks, Qt Creator, Anjuta, and Eclipse with the CDT plugin.